# Alternatives for Heroku

Tags: heroku, render

I always using Heroku to deploy my works from GitHub,
But last time I surprised that when I want to add a Database to my work 'on Heroku' its ask me to insert my payment methods even if its free, and I really got freak to add them so I don't wanna to add any card.

Now I trying to search for alternative site that gives me ability to deploy me GitHub repository and adding Databases for free.

I found 'Render' but its not free.
Can you plz advice what can I use.

Best regards.

Comment: Recommendation requests are off-topic for stack overflow, but this may be on topic for [softwarerecs.se].  But first, check out their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku provides a free tier for dynos and for the Postgres add-on, so you will be fine as long as you stay on the free plan (which takes effort to upgrade, so no need to worry about surprise charges). Credit Card details are used a bit for verification/validation and in the case that you upgrade your plans.

Per [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification)

> Heroku needs to be able to reliably identify and contact our users in the event of an issue. We have found that having a credit card on file provides the most reliable way of obtaining verified contact information. Account verification also helps us prevent abuse.